# ApplyMap function on Multiple columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe

```
dd = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,5,3],'b':[3,2,3],'c':[2,4,5]})

   a  b  c
0  1  3  2
1  5  2  4
2  3  3  5
```

I just want to replace numbers of column a and b which are smaller than column c numbers. I want to this operation row wise

I did this

```
dd.applymap(lambda x: 0 if x < x['c'] else x )
```

I get error

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

I understood x is a int but how to get value of column c for that row

I want this output

```
   a  b  c
0  0  3  2
1  5  0  4
2  0  0  5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with [`DataFrame.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html):

```
df = dd.mask(dd.lt(dd['c'], axis=0), 0)
print (df)
   a  b  c
0  0  3  2
1  5  0  4
2  0  0  5
```

Or you can set values by compare broadcasting by column `c`:

```
dd[dd < dd['c'].to_numpy()[:, None]] = 0
print (dd)
   a  b  c
0  0  3  2
1  5  0  4
2  0  0  5
```